# Проблема с firebase storage и picasso

Tags: android, firebase, picasso

My Upload Code :

```
package com.example.mfapp;

public class Upload {
    private String mName;
    private String mImageUrl;

    public Upload() {

    }

    public Upload(String name, String imageUrl) {
        if (name.trim().equals("")) {
            name = "No Name";
        }
        mName = name;
        mImageUrl = imageUrl;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        mName = name;
    }




    public void getImageUrl(String ImageUrl) {
        mImageUrl = ImageUrl;

    }
}
```

My ImageAdapter :

```
package com.example.mfapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private List<Upload> mUploads;
public  ImageAdapter(Context context,List<Upload> uploads){
    mContext = context;
    mUploads = uploads;
}


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ImageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
       View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.image_item,parent,false);
       return  new ImageViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
Upload uploadCurrent = mUploads.get(position);
holder.textViewName.setText(uploadCurrent.getName());

        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUploads.size();
    }

    public  class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewName;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ImageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            textViewName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_upload);
        }
    }

}
```

Error in this string :

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);
```

У меня ошибка в 39 строке. D:\MFAPP\app\src\main\java\com\example\mfapp\ImageAdapter.java:39: error: method getImageUrl in class Upload cannot be applied to given types; .load(uploadCurrent.getImageUrl()).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.imageView); ^ required: String found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Answer (score 0):

Написано же:
**getImageUrl in class Upload cannot be applied to given types**
**required: String found: no arguments**
Вы не передаёте методу требуемый аргумент. Посмотрим на сам метод:

```
public void getImageUrl(String ImageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = ImageUrl;
}
```

и видим что он требует на вход строку и на самом деле является сеттером, вопреки своему имени. Исправляем ситуацию, оформив правильную пару:

```
public void getImageUrl() {
    return mImageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    mImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```